# Realm. Android when call method realm.close()?

Tags: android, realm

I want to sync realm with many devices. So I need after update local realm the data must upload to Relm Object Server (ROS).

Here code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }


    @Override
    public void addOrUpdateOrganisation(final String orgranisationJson) {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(Organisation.class, orgranisationJson);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

But data not update.

But when I try this code then data success update local and sucess sync.

```
   @Override
public void addOrUpdateOrganisation(final String orgranisationJson) {
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // need for update data
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(Organisation.class, orgranisationJson);
            }
        });
}
```

But in mehtod "addOrUpdateOrganisation" I'm not close realm.

Questions:

- Is I need in every method (e.g. **addOrUpdateOrganisation**) get instance of Realm by  **Realm.getDefaultInstance()** ?
- When I must call method **realm.close** ? In every method or only in **onDestroy**()?

Comment: See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances . Basica rule is: ou need to call `close()` on every return value of `getXxxInstance()`.

Comment: If I call close() after every getXXXInstance() then data change only in local realm db, but NOT upload to remote realm db (realm db is not synchronize).

Comment: Uh, we have an open issue for this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5028 It caused by the sync session is stopped after all Realm instances are closed. Current workaround would be keeping a Realm instance alive on UI thread (since Realm instance will be auto updated in the looper thread, so the instance on UI thread won't cause too much side effect plus normally UI thread always needs a Realm instance). But yes, this is a problem and we should fix it.